Why Shrinkwrap doesn't work
can someone explain me why the Shrinkwrap modifier didn't work normaly in my situation

Are you sure your scale and rotation are applied? Ctrl + A > Scale/Rotation

Give it a direction to project, in your case it should be the Y direction, assuming you've applied rotation. Also play with the Positive and Negative buttons to see what works better
